# cake php framework on ubuntu server webroot doesn't work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp, ubuntu

I upload a Cakephp app to Ubuntu server.

In /var/www/UCABsocial put all files

http://ec2-54-226-209-240.compute-1.amazonaws.com/UCABsocial/

The server doesn't resolve the webroot url (path)

```
GET http://ec2-54-226-209-240.compute-1.amazonaws.com/UCABsocial/css/bootstrap.css 404 (Not Found) ec2-54-226-209-240.compute-1.amazonaws.com/:6
GET http://ec2-54-226-209-240.compute-1.amazonaws.com/UCABsocial/css/flat-ui.css 404 (Not Found) ec2-54-226-209-240.compute-1.amazonaws.com/:6
GET http://ec2-54-226-209-240.compute-1.amazonaws.com/UCABsocial/css/demo.css 404 (Not Found) ec2-54-226-209-240.compute-1.amazonaws.com/:6
GET http://ec2-54-226-209-240.compute-1.amazonaws.com/UCABsocial/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js 404 (Not Found)
```

I hope you can help me to fix it.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What did you do other than just upload the files?

Comment: did you configure apache mod_rewrite? if not, refer this http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html

Comment: since [this shows where your css files are](http://ec2-54-226-209-240.compute-1.amazonaws.com/UCABsocial/app/webroot/css/) it's clear that mod rewrite is not enabled, and you're currently using a [development install](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html#development) - The document root for your application [should be the webroot folder](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html#production) not the path to the root of your appilcation.